# Reproduce Windows Product Key Input

Tags: .net

I'm starting to put together an activation dialog as part of my application. I *really* like the way Microsoft did theirs recently with Windows 7, more specifically the way the hyphens that separate each quintet of the product key are added and removed automatically.

After taking a quick look at it, it seems like it's a bit more difficult to implement smoothly than I had first though. That or I've been starring at the issue for too long. Is there any sample code or tutorial that reproduces this behavior for a TextBox?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's code or tute to do exactly what you want. If you want to entice getting people to come up with something, try offering a bounty.

Comment: You're not talking about a masked textbox are you?

Comment: I was thinking a little bit more than just a masked TextBox. For example, with the example I mentioned, dashes are automatically as necessary. Some product key input fields seems like they're straight from Hell, while it seems like this is one that Microsoft got right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a "MaskedTextBox" control

```
public void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = "0000 - 0000 - 0000 - 0000";
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx